# php adding wrong value to mySql database

Tags: php, mysql

i have built an air for android app that posts content to facebook and on success sends a url query to a php file to add the post id of the content along with `fb_id` and the users name. the problem is it is not adding the value i am giving it it is instead adding the same number(dont know where it is coming from) to the `post_id` and `fb_id`. i know the right values are being sent by the mobile app.

php:

```
<?php
/*
------------variables set in flash--------------

 videoVars.postId = result.id
 videoVars.uid = uid //fb user id
 videoVars.firstName = firstName
 videoVars.lastName = lastName

*/

$postId = $_REQUEST['postId'];
$uid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
$firstName = $_REQUEST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_REQUEST['lastName'];

echo $postId.'<br/>';
echo $uid.'<br/>';
echo $firstName.'<br/>';
echo $lastName.'<br/>';



//connect to database
include('db-connect.php');

$addVideo = mysqli_query($dbc , "INSERT INTO content (content_id, post_id, fb_id, first_name, last_name ) VALUES('','".$postId."','".$uid."','".$firstName."','".$lastName."')");

?>
```

the value i am getting for post_id and user_id are the same even though they should be different. i manually typed the vars in to addressbar in browser and it still misbehaved in the same way. the only way i can add more than one row is to add it in the sql tab of `phpMyAdmin`

Comment: what is the structure of table content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the id were being stored as ints in the database and the biggest allowable int value is `2147483647` which is being put in each time and as the numeric ids are bigger numbers than `2147483647` and one of the fields is set to unique it can only add one row. i have changed the type to bigint and it is working fine now. i have also implemented some of `@ dAngelov` suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If your echo calls output the correct values, check your database table structure and make sure there's no `UNIQUE` key set for `fb_id`.

Then, make sure you're escaping all your content with `mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Is `content_id` an `auto_increment` value? If so, try passing `NULL` for it, without the single quotes, instead of an empty string.

To debug, you can also try echoing your query (first assign it to a variable `$sql = "[QUERY HERE]";`, then pass the variable to the function, then echo the `$sql` variable and finally call your file manually.

Comment: the `post_id` is set to unique that is why im only getting one entry because i am a number that will be unique every time but the correct number is not going in. i will edit Q.

Comment: Do your `echo` calls show the correct data? Did you try to echo the `$sql` query to see what you're sending to db?

Comment: yes i echo ed the query and the correct values are getting echoed out. and still not going to database

Comment: What's your table structure? If you copy the MySQL query manually from your PHP file's echo, and into PhpMyAdmin or Sequel Pro, does it still enter the wrong values?

Comment: i cant Because there are variables in statement. it works from the php file if i hard code the values but that is no use to me.

Comment: You can, if you first assign the query to a variable, as I suggested. Give that a try.

Comment: i did assign the query to a variable but there are variables within the query

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO content (content_id, post_id, fb_id, first_name, last_name ) VALUES('','".$postId."','".$uid."','".$firstName."','".$lastName."')"; echo $sql; mysqli_query($dbc ,$sql);`

^ try the above.

Comment: that looks exactly the same as the query i had gave the same result

Comment: The output from $sql above - does it show the different numbers, or does it show the same number?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have problem on content_id field. it should has auto_increment property.

In your sql, when you inserts content_id as a blank value '' it will convert to 0, next time when you insert a blank value again you will has "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'" message.

to fix it just remove the primary key field in your query
i.e:

```
$addVideo = mysqli_query($dbc , "INSERT INTO content ( post_id, fb_id, first_name, last_name ) VALUES('".$postId."','".$uid."','".$firstName."','".$lastName."')");
```

Or you can insert a null value for it:

```
$addVideo = mysqli_query($dbc , "INSERT INTO content (content_id, post_id, fb_id, first_name, last_name ) VALUES(null,'".$postId."','".$uid."','".$firstName."','".$lastName."')");
```

You can try to print out your current - wrong sql error like this:

```
$addVideo = mysqli_query($dbc , "INSERT INTO content (content_id, post_id, fb_id, first_name, last_name ) VALUES('','".$postId."','".$uid."','".$firstName."','".$lastName."')");
if (!$addVideo) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbc));
    }
```

Comment: any time i used ai values before i just used `''` and it worked without any issue. also i have edited the question